# How to retrieve the rows from mysql whose field value should start with alphabet?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to retrieve the rows from mysql table, whose field values should start with alphabeic letter and the value may contain numeric values along with letters.

```
Eg:
==
id : BKDyriu3
id : 12387545
id : YDfhety7
```

How can I retrieve id field which starts with letter ?

Can anyone please help me out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`ASCII()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_ascii) function.

> Returns the numeric value of the leftmost character of the string str.
>   Returns 0 if str is the empty string. Returns NULL if str is NULL

```
SELECT * FROM your_table 
WHERE ASCII(id) BETWEEN 65 AND 90 
      OR 
      ASCII(id) BETWEEN 97 AND 122
```

- Uppercase A-Z has ASCII value range from 65 to 90.
- Lowercase a-z has ASCII value range from 97 to 122.

Comment: @fervent happy to help :)